# Scrapy: POST request returning JSON response (200 OK) but with incomplete data

Tags: javascript, python, json, scrapy

MySpider is trying to depict the load-more action click which results in loading of more items on web-page dyanamically. And this continues until nothing more is left to be loaded.

```
yield FormRequest(url,headers=header,formdata={'entity_id': '70431','profile_action': 'review-top','page':str(p), 'limit': '5'},callback=self.parse_review)

header = {#'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0',
               'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
               'Host': 'www.zomato.com',
               'Accept': '*/*',
               'Referer': 'https://www.zomato.com',
               'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
               'dont_filter':'True' }

url = 'https://www.zomato.com/php/social_load_more.php'
```

The response received is the json response.

```
jsonresponse = json.load(response)
```

And i do see -

```
('data==', {u'status': u'success', u'left_count': 0, u'html': u"<script type='text/javascript'>if (typeof initiateLaziness == 'function') initiateLaziness() </script>", u'page': u'1', u'more': 0})
```

U see i get response for status, left_count, page, more.
However i am interested in 'html'. Unfortunately, its the **in-correct** value which i do receive if done through browser(inspected the network calls and verified)

Expected 'html' is ----

```
<div><a> very long html stuff...............................................<div><script type='text/javascript'>if (typeof initiateLaziness == 'function') initiateLaziness() </script>
```

I am receiving only later part

```
<script>...................................</script>.
```

Real html stuff is missing.

Thing to note is that i do receive response but incomplete one for 'html' only.All good for rest. I believe it might be something related to dynamically generated html. But i am getting any clue on it.

No content-length is added by scrapy middleware. And not allowing me to add one as well. Respons fails with 400 when adding it to header.

Request Header being actually sent to server:

```
 {'Accept-Language': ['en'], 'Accept-Encoding': ['gzip, deflate,br'], 'Dont_Filter': ['True'], 'Connection': ['keep-alive'], 'Accept': ['*/*'], 'User-Agent': ['Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0'], 'Host': ['www.zomato.com'], 'X-Requested-With': ['XMLHttpRequest'], 'Cookie': ['zl=en; fbtrack=9be27330646d24088c56c2531ea2fbf5; fbcity=7; PHPSESSID=2338004ce3fd540477242c3eaee685168163bd05'], 'Referer': ['https://www.zomato.com'], 'Content-Type': ['application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8']})
```

Can any one please help me if i am missing anything here?
Or someway i can sent the send the content-length/or make middleware sent it for me?
Many Thanks.

Comment: One thing i noticed is that after adding "Content-Length : 50" to header, the response fails. Also, middle-ware is not adding it automatically to header of request.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get the html content in response because of not using cookies. In the actual request header that you have mentioned, there is a cookie attribute. But in the ajax request you are sending through your code, there is no cookie field.

First a cookie is set in the response to the request made from zomato's restaurant page with the url: https://www.zomato.com/city/restaurant/reviews.  Now, when the load more button is clicked, a request is sent with the cookie field containing the cookie set by the server in the previous response to the url 'https://www.zomato.com/php/social_load_more.php'. So, everytime an ajax request is made, the cookie that was set in the previous response should be sent in the request header and a new cookie will be set in the response of the present request.

So, in order to manage these cookies, I used session object of requests package. The script can be written without using scrapy also. As you wrote your code in scrapy, see if there are any session objects available to manage the cookies for scrapy.

My code :

```
import requests
url : 'https://www.zomato.com/city/restaurant/reviews' 
s = requests.Session()
resp = s.get(url, headers=header)
```

The above code is to send requests to the url of the restaurant reviews. This is essential because the first cookie is set in the response to this request.

```
params={
        'entity_id':res_id,
        'profile_action':'reviews-dd',
        'page':'1',
        'limit':'5'
    }
header = {"origin":"https://www.zomato.com","Referer":"https://www.zomato.com/","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0", "x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest", 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
loadreviews_text = s.post("https://www.zomato.com/php/social_load_more.php", data=params, headers=header)
loadreviews = loadreviews_text.json()
```

Now a request is made to the social_load_more.php. The object 's' manages the cookies. The variable loadreviews will now have the html data in json format.