# Scrapy not adding content-length to FormRequest header

Tags: python, cookies, request, scrapy

This is in reference to following issue :

[Scrapy: POST request returning JSON response (200 OK) but with incomplete data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160625/scrapy-post-request-returning-json-response-200-ok-but-with-incomplete-data?s=12|0.0000)

Here I believe, there are like two problems which are related to each-other:

**1) Content-Length is not added to Header by scrapy.**

```
header = {#'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Host': 'www.zomato.com',
           'Accept': '*/*',
           'Referer': 'https://www.zomato.com',
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
           'dont_filter':'True' }
```

**Actual header sent to server does not contain Content-Length**

I believe its for this reason, the response does not contain the expected value.
Note: Instead I see cookies being added automatically to header by scrapy before sending it to server.

**To sort this out manually, I am trying to set Content-Length manually.**

```
header = {#'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0',
       'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
       'Host': 'www.zomato.com',
       'Accept': '*/*',
       'Referer': 'https://www.zomato.com',
       'Content-Length':'57'
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
       'dont_filter':'True' }
```

**But I now get the 400 bad request error for this request**

I tried disabling cookies to give a try by adding to scrapy.cfg

```
COOKIES_ENABLE = False
```

But I still see cookies being added to request by scrapy.

Also, I added following to scrapy.cfg

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES ={'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware':None,
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware':None,
}
```

Again no luck.

Can anyone please assist me on this? Struggling to get this resolved since last 3 days. :(

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you capture the actual headers being sent and post them?

Answer (score 0):

Can you run your spider against this server code and capture the headers?

```
import BaseHTTPServer

class Handler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        print(self.headers)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

def run():
    server_address = ('', 8001)
    httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(server_address, Handler)
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Sure. I will get back with the request and response header for this.

Comment: Before, I could try, I had this solved using Selenium Webdriver. I managed to fire the click event and Webdriver did all for me. I now got hold of new html rendered within driver and could scrap the required tags within. 
But I will provide you the results for your request sooner.